# How to save dynamically added form inputs after validation fails in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a problem with my form. So, I have some fields that are generetad when user click on link, and those fields are lost after I press form Submit button if validation fails. If validation pass, everything is correct and data is saved into database.

So these are that fields, and also script to add new field:

View:

```
<tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
     <!-- <td><input type="text" name="date[]" value="" /></td>-->
      <td><input type="text" name="work[]" value="" class="task" />
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('work[]');?></span>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="partner[]" value="<?php echo set_value('partner[]'); ?>" />
      </td>
      <td>
      <select name="director[]">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Director</option>
        <option value="hkn">HKN</option>
        <option value="anita">Anita</option>
        <option value="ravi">Ravi</option>
        <option value="ameesha">Ameesha</option>
      </select>
      <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('director[]');?></span>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="time[]" value="" />
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('time[]');?></span>
      </td>
      <td>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="task[]" rows="2" id=""></textarea>
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('task[]');?></span>
      </td>
      <td><textarea class="form-control" name="status[]" rows="2" id=""></textarea>
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('status[]');?></span>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Controller:

```
function add_task(){
        /* Checking the all validation of task form*/
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('work[]', 'Types of Work', 'required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('partner[]', 'Worked With', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('director[]', 'Director', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('time[]', 'No Of Hours', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('task[]', 'Task Details', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('status[]', 'Task Status', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            /* Taking the data from form*/
            $todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
            $work=$this->input->post('work');
            $partner=$this->input->post('partner');
            $director=$this->input->post('director');
            $time=$this->input->post('time');
            $task=$this->input->post('task');
            $status=$this->input->post('status');

            $count=count($this->input->post('work'));
            $data =array();
            for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
            $data[$i] = array(
                'name'       =>$this->session->userdata('emp_name'),
                'date'       =>$todayDate,
                'work'       =>$work[$i],
                'partner'    =>$partner[$i],
                'director'   =>$director[$i],
                'time'       =>$time[$i],
                'task'       =>$task[$i],
                'status'     =>$status[$i]
                );
                }
                $add=$this->digital_hodm_model->add_task($data);
                /* Display Success message if data inserted successfully in database*/

                    if($add){
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form',"All HODM Data Inserted Successfully.");
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form_class','alert-success');
                    }else{
                        /* Displaying the error message*/
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form',"failed to add, Please Try again");
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form_class','alert-danger');
                    }
                return redirect('home');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('public/digital_hodm_view');
        }
    }
```

So my question is: is it possible to save dynamically generated form fields and their values after validation fails and how?

Thank you

Comment: yes its posibile witth localstorage/sessionstorage + some javascript

Comment: @madalin but how .I dont know how to do this

Comment: use the algorithm divide-et-impera and brake down your problem in smaller managibile problems

Comment: I didn't get you @madalin.

Comment: use localstorage to save the state of the dynamically added elements on error, if there are errors in the localstorage display them, if submit is successful clear the localstorage,this is a simple implementation

Comment: @madalin I am new in codeigniter .I dont know how to do this

Comment: this is done with javascript,from the looks of it you are new to it as well

Comment: if you want to do it with php you will need to save the state of the dynamically added elements in a hidden input and then append the value of the input on error to the page